Socket.io Repeatedly Connecting and Disconnecting with Express JS Server
I am working on a React JS project, where I want real-time full duplex communication of client and server (both deployed on Vercel). For this, I tried to implement the websockets using Socket.io library, but it is continuously giving me strange errors on my Firefox browser console.
Firefox version: 192.0 (64-bit)
Socket.io, Socket.io-client versions: both 4.7.5
Here is my server-side code:
import { Server } from "socket.io"
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
    res.send('valid response from server')
})
const server = app.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('server is listening')
})

const socketServer = new Server(server,{
    cors:{
        origin:'https://miscapp.vercel.app',
        methods: ['GET','POST'],
        credentials: true,
        allowedHeaders:["my-custom-header"]
    }
})
socketServer.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('established', 'server said it is connected')
    socket.on('message',() => {
        socket.emit('message','message from server')
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.emit('message','server disconnected')
    })
})

And the client-side code (App.js):
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('https://miscapp-server.vercel.app',{
  withCredentials: true,
  extraHeaders:{
    'my-custom-header':'abcd'
  }
})

socket.on('connect',() => {
  socket.on('established', (data) => {
    console.log('server is connected, data: ',data)
  })
  socket.on('message',(message) => {
    console.log('message: ',message)
  })
  socket.on('connect_error',(error) => {
    console.log('message: ',error.message)
    console.log('code: ',error.code)
    console.log('description: ',error.description)
    console.log('context: ',error.context)
  })
  socket.on('beforeunload',() => {
    socket.close()
  })
})
function App() {
  function handler(){
    console.log('inside handler')
    socket.emit('message','this is a message from client')
  }
  useEffect(() => {
  },[])
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handler}>request</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


When I open my website using the url miscapp.vercel.app, I see those errors on my browser console, some of them regularly repeating themselves.
repeating errors on browser console
these errors do not repeat very often, they appear randomly

You should move your socket connection inside a useEffect hook, you can take a look at the code sample here for additional guide https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react.

Actually, the problem was with the way Vercel handles the requests at the backend. It use serverless functions with a maximum execution limit, and socket connections cannot persist in this short amount of time. I had to use Ably platform to get it working right.
